# How to melt multiple columns into one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table:

```
a   b   c   d    e    f   19-08-06   19-08-07   19-08-08   g    h    i
1   2   3   4    5    6      7         8           9      10    11   12
```

I have 34 columns of the date, so I want to melt the date columns to be into one column only.

How can I do this in pyhton?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please define your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to create a boolean mask for extracting date columns, then use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
m = df.columns.str.fullmatch("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
cols = df.columns[m]

df.melt(value_vars=cols, var_name='date', value_name='vals')

       date  vals
0  19-08-06     7
1  19-08-07     8
2  19-08-08     9
```

If you want to melt while keeping other columns then try this.

```
df.melt(
    id_vars=df.columns.difference(cols), var_name="date", value_name="vals"
)

  a  b  c  d  e  f   g   h   i      date  vals
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  10  11  12  19-08-06     7
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  10  11  12  19-08-07     8
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  10  11  12  19-08-08     9
```

Here I did not use `value_vars=cols` as it's done implicitly

```
value_vars: tuple, list, or ndarray, optional
   Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are 
   not set as id_vars.
```

Comment: thankyou! I tried it, but I got error when I defined "m". The error said: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. How to fix this?

Comment: Whats the output of `print(m)`? @yangyang

Comment: I got: Index([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
      dtype='object')

Comment: was it because my date is in this format: 2019-08-13 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Then replace `.fullmatch` with `.match` @yangyang

Comment: I did it already, still gave error said: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: `print(df.columns)`? @yangyang

Comment: it gave me all my columns names, including the date columns

Comment: @yangyang I meant post the output of `print(df.columns)` here.